# Calculate number of digits of a decimal number in c

Tags: c, algorithm, digits

how am I supposed to find the number of digits of decimal numbers in c?
ex. find how many digits are in 123.4567?!

Comment: Is this a number that came from input or was it calculated?

Comment: @RetiredNinja number came from user input

Comment: If it comes from input, you can input a string. How to count the digits in `"123.4567?!"`...? With a loop and `isdigit()`.

Comment: I would accept the input as a string and use `strlen` to get the length. If you need to convert the value to a float or double later you can do that. You will need to keep in mind that the input string may not be exactly representable as a floating point value so you may not be able to get the exact input back if you convert back to a string. Explaining why you need the length and how you plan to use it would help get better advice.

Comment: @RetiredNinja this was a question on my exam paper... the full question goes like...
Reading numbers from a text file , where numbers are divided from each other by a space
find with recursion which of numbers has most digits (numbers my be in decimal).

Comment: It sounds like the exam question boils down to "find the longest string in the file" since you really don't care about the actual value of the number.

Comment: Please update the question to state exactly where this number or numeral is coming from, e.g., that they it is in input from a file or terminal in some stream-of-characters format, rather than being in a `float` or `double` object.

Comment: The question is quite incomplete as regards the exact syntax of the strings that are accepted as valid decimal numbers, and how invalids strings should be handled (rejected, accepted if they contain a valid number, or simply guaranteed to not arise).

Comment: @Fe2O3: I am sorry to disagree. I am used to the terminology "decimal number" for 123.4567, and the corresponding decimal fraction would be 1234567/10000, which is indeed a fraction.

Comment: Have you ever worked with normal decimal numbers in school? Like dividing `12.34` with `10` (or multiplying these two numbers) to get a result? If you can do such a division or multiplication using pen and paper you can do the operations needed to figure out the number of digits in an arbitrary decimal number as well (if you limit yourself to a certain number of significant digits).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how am I supposed to find the number of digits of decimal numbers in
> c? ex. find how many digits are in 123.4567?

Start by converting it to a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main() {
    char input[] = "123.456";

    int i, d = 0, count = 0, len = strlen(input);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (input[i] == '.') {
        if (++d == 1) {
        printf("int count %d\n", count);
        if (i == 0) {
            break;
        }
        continue;
        }
        // 2 or more decimal points.
        break;
    }
    if (isdigit(input[i])) {
        count++;
        continue;
    }
    // Found a non-digit non-decimal point.
    if (i == 0) {
        printf("int count %d\n", count);
    }
    break;
    }
    printf("all count %d\n", count);
}
```

Comment: I rather think he wants double not trivial string

Comment: @JamesRisner: I see nowhere a formal definition of "my be in decimal". In my humble understanding, integers should be accepted, as well as signed numbers. I am voting to close the question, as being too imprecise (not counting that it is completely off-topic as showing no effort.)

Answer (score 0):

Little project for a slow day...

Make use of standard C library functions and keep track of counts. (This doesn't deal with the trivial 'unary minus'.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char *input[] = {
        "1", "123", "123.",
        "123.4", "0.456", ".456",
        "0.100000", // very precise!!
        ".2.3", "1..3",
        "foobar", "foo.bar",
    };

    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof input/sizeof input[0]; i++ ) {
        char *str = input[i];

        int len = strlen( str );
        int dp = 0;
        int lenFrac = 0;
        int lenWhol = strspn( str, "0123456789" );
        if( str[lenWhol] == '.' )
            dp++, lenFrac = strspn( str + lenWhol + 1, "0123456789" );

        printf( "str '%s', whole(%d), frac(%d), digits(%d)",
            str, lenWhol, lenFrac, lenWhol + lenFrac );

        int want = lenWhol + dp + lenFrac;
        if( lenWhol < 1 && lenFrac < 1 ) want = -1;

        printf( "  %swell formed\n", len != want ? "not " : "" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
str '1', whole(1), frac(0), digits(1)  well formed
str '123', whole(3), frac(0), digits(3)  well formed
str '123.', whole(3), frac(0), digits(3)  well formed
str '123.4', whole(3), frac(1), digits(4)  well formed
str '0.456', whole(1), frac(3), digits(4)  well formed
str '.456', whole(0), frac(3), digits(3)  well formed
str '0.100000', whole(1), frac(6), digits(7)  well formed
str '.2.3', whole(0), frac(1), digits(1)  not well formed
str '1..3', whole(1), frac(0), digits(1)  not well formed
str 'foobar', whole(0), frac(0), digits(0)  not well formed
str 'foo.bar', whole(0), frac(0), digits(0)  not well formed
```

Answer (score -2):

Beware that the "number of digits" in an actual floating-point number is more complicated than it sounds, and is ultimately rather meaningless.

If you say

```
float f = 123.4567;
```

that number might actually be found to have 20 decimal digits.  The reason is that the number 123.4567 cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point.  The closest number which can be represented as a `float` is 123.45670318603515625.

Similarly, if you say

```
double d = 123.4567;
```

that number might seem to have more like 49 digits.  Type `double` can't represent 123.4567 either, but since it has more precision it can get closer: 123.4566999999999978854248183779418468475341796875.

If you're reading a number in from the user, and if you're reading it in as a *string* (not a `float` or a `double`), then you can count the number of digits exactly, without as many surprises.  On the other hand, you then have to worry about what answer you want if the user types something like `000123.4567000`.  (I'm not sure how one might deal with an input like `123e45`, either.)

Comment: Who said that "123.4567" is a floating-point number ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It sure looks like one!

Comment: You confuse fractional and floating-point number. A floating-point number does not look like anything as long as you don't convert it to a printing form using some format.  It could even be emitted as raw hex data.

Comment: “123.4567” in source code is what the C standard causes a “floating constant.” Presumably that is an abbreviated version of “floating-point constant,” and it is such only because that source code is translated into a floating-point value. The floating-point types, such as `double`, are actual floating-point types because they have a component that scales the number, making the decimal point float. But “123.4567” as a numeral by itself, not part of C source code, is not floating-point, because the point is fixed right there in one spot, with no exponent scaling it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The OP is dealing with strings of characters, not numerical variables, and no C constant is involved (by the way 123.4567 would implicitly be double, not float). 123.4567 and 1.234567e2 could be stored as the same floating-point number, one being written in the usual format and the other in the *scientific* format.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: The context for my comment is Steve Summit’s comment that “123.4567” looks like a floating-point number, plus the fact that OP is interpreting a string, not a `float`, `double`, or other floating-point type. Given that OP is interpreting a string, “123.4567” is **not** a floating-point number. It is a string of characters. Also, 123.4567 cannot be stored as a floating-point number in the formats commonly used for `float` and `double`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I am not in disagreement with you.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Not to prolong the discussion, but for the record: My "looks like one!" comment was somewhat flip, but it was because I didn't know how to answer your "Who said?" question.  I mean, yes, obviously nobody said it *was* a floating-point number, but equally obviously (or so I thought), someone might have thought it was one, and since it's quite meaningless to talk about the number of decimal digits in a binary floating-point number, I thought it was worth making that point.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Not to prolong the discussion, but for the record: Since we write these answers for posterity, not just to help the OP today, and since a later reader wanting to "Calculate number of digits of a decimal number" might well have been working with an actual `float` or `double`, I thought it was worth making this point.  Indeed, the OP of this question, in trying to better discriminate between valid and invalid decimal digit strings, might well have veered towards a solution that involved actual floating-point.

Comment: @SteveSummit: a float/double is anything but decimal. You might consider that it has bits, but not digits. You keep fuelling the confusion.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Who said that a float/double is decimal? :-)